# How to export objects from R to php or python

Tags: php, r

I have run three machine learning models with the caret library (Random Forest, svm and neural network) and saved them in one Rdata object. Is there a way to export them so that we can import them in php format and integrate them into a tool programmed in php?

It would also be useful for me to be able to export them in python format.

Thank you very much for the help

Alberto

Comment: If the object you're exporting are R classes, I don't see any way to convert them back into something readable by python or php. You should build your own objects and use serialization to transfer them from R to python, php or any other language. You could also use the reticulate package in R to serialize them directly using the pickle package in python (just my best guess, I have never tried this last option)...